# How to read SQL rows as PowerShell parameters

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell, azure-automation

On Azure, I am running multiple .sql files from a container in 100s of Azure SQL Databases via Powershell runbook.

I want Powershell to read the **server name** and the **database name** to run the scripts from my SQL Server table that looks like this:

| Servername | Databasename | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Server-01 | DB-01 | Process |
| Server-01 | DB-02 | Skip |
| Server-02 | DB-03 | Process |

In my current version of the Powershell script, it can read the files in the container and run them in a given server and database:

```
# Get the blob container
$blobs = Get-AzStorageContainer -Name $containerName  -Context $ctx | Get-AzStorageBlob 

# Download the blob content to localhost and execute each one 
foreach ($blob in $blobs)
    {
        $file = Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $containerName -Blob $blob.Name  -Destination "." -Context $ctx 
        Write-Output ("Processing file :" + $file.Name)
        $query = Get-Content -Path $file.Name
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "Server-01.database.windows.net" -Database "DB-01" -Query $query -AccessToken $access_token
        Write-Output ("This file is executed :" + $file.Name) 
    }
```

I am looking for a method that will read the rows from the table and feed them into the **-ServerInstance** and **-Database** fields in the *Invoke-Sqlcmd*. Ideally it can filter out the **Skip** rows.

Comment: Is your intent to run the same script against each database in the SQL table with Status = 'Process'?

Comment: Where is this table of server names and database stored?

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes, same script in multiple databases in multiple servers where it says 'Process'

Comment: @Larnu The table is stored in another Azure SQL Database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to load the database list into a `DataTable` and iterate over the list for each query. Change the `$databaseListConnectionString` in the example code below per your authentication method and set the connection `AccessToken` if/as needed.

```
# get database list
$databaseListConnectionString = "Data Source=YourServer;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase"
$databaseListQuery = "SELECT ServerName, DatabaseName FROM dbo.DatabaseList WHERE Status = 'Process';"
$dataAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($databaseListQuery, $databaseListConnectionString)
$dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection.AccessToken = $access_token
$databaseList = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
[void]$dataAdapter.Fill($databaseList)

# Get the blob container
$blobs = Get-AzStorageContainer -Name $containerName  -Context $ctx | Get-AzStorageBlob 

# Download the blob content to localhost and execute each one 
foreach ($blob in $blobs) {
    {
        $file = Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $containerName -Blob $blob.Name  -Destination "." -Context $ctx 
        Write-Output ("Processing file :" + $file.Name)
        $query = Get-Content -Path $file.Name
        foreach($database in $databaseList.Rows) {
            Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$($database.ServerName)" -Database "$($database.DatabaseName)" -Query $query -AccessToken $access_token
            Write-Output ("This file is executed :" + $file.Name)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I've been trying this method with my authentication method and failing. The SQL Server - Runbook connection is done via a Private endpoint and I am using an access token for my "Invoke-Sqlcmd" command. Is there a way I can follow a similar way for the "$databaseListConnectionString" here?

Comment: @Strayda, try adding this line after instantiating the new SqlDataAdapter: `$dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection.AccessToken = $access_token`. I think you can remove `;Integrated Security=SSPI` from the connection string with the token.

Comment: You are a hero! Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I'll edited my answer for your use case.